# Using the new Message Template admin screen, how can I see whether a given template is the default or has been customised?

Tags: message-templates

Looking at the new message template admin interface provided by the Message Administration extension, I can't work out how to see at a glance whether a given template is the default, or whether it's been customised. This is a really useful feature of the original admin interface. I hope it's not being discarded. Or maybe it is there and I'm just missing it?

Comment: It's a missing feature. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4452. Consider also https://civicrm.org/extensions/better-message-templates

Comment: is there some trick that all the default ones are odd numbered IDs and custom ones are even? or does this not apply in the SK/FB universe

Comment: @petednz You know how in the regular interface there will be a "revert to default" if you've customized it? There is nothing like that in the message admin extension. The ids of the "reserved" vs the "in-use" don't tell you anything about whether you've edited the in-use one from when it was last in sync with the reserved one since the ids don't change and there will be two for each template regardless.

Comment: good point. but in the database log_civicrm_msg_template it would show if the even IDs were more recently updated than the odd IDs - perhaps helps if Graham is stuck without the 'old' feature till it gets added?